# Encode Emoji to string

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

I want to encode this emoji  to string:

I have tried like this:

```
let data = self.comment.dataUsingEncoding(NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
if let data = data {
   let emojiString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
       self.comment = emojiString
}
```

but it doesn't work.

[image]

I want to encode like `&#128520;` , not `\ud83d\ude08`

So how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`128520` is the *unicode scalar value* of "":

```
let text =  ""

let encoded = text.unicodeScalars.map {
    "&#" + String($0.value) + ";"
}.joinWithSeparator("")

print(encoded) // &#128520;&#128512;
```

Comment: This helps me. Thanks a lot @Martin R .

Comment: it should be `let unicode = text.unicodeScalars.map({
    "&#" + String($0.value)
}).joinWithSeparator(",")` to get expected string :D

Comment: @Hoa: OP said: *"I want to encode like &#128520;"* and that is the syntax of XML "character entities". But anyway, it should be easy to adapt the example code to the concrete needs.